# Firefox 38.0.5 debugger is now pulling Typescript

Tags: firefox, typescript, firebug

I just upgraded to version 38.0.5 of Firefox and now when I look in my debug script window native or firebug it shows the TS not the JS. Also in my production environment it also shows ts where we didn't even publish the ts only the js gets published... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely reason: you are using Source Maps.

When you use source maps, the browser is able to show the source code that relates to the transpiled JavaScript code.

You can switch source maps on and off as it is a compiler setting.

```
tsc --sourceMap app.ts
```